# is it possible to set default open folder for File Explorer of Windows 10 version 1903 opened from Taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, windows-10-v1903

Windows 10: version 1903

I tried rename "Libraries folder" into "File Explorer" and replace the "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\File Explorer.lnk", but the Taskbar show two folder, one is the "File Explorer" that open my computer as default another is the "Libraries folder".

At windows 7, I can change the target from a .lnk property, but in windows 10, it seem we cannot edit the target field.

is it possible to set File Explorer's default open "Libraries folder" when opened from Taskbar? (in ideal, there is one file explorer pinned to the taskbar, you click it a "Libraries folder" opened, after all only one file explorer show in taskbar)

Answer (score 0):

You can open Libraries directly by creating a shortcut that will call
`explorer.exe shell:Libraries`.

Many more `shell:` commands exist. They are all listed in the article
[Shell Commands to Access the Special Folders in Windows 10/8/7/Vista/XP](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/).

Comment: yes, we can pin it to the taskbar, but when you click it, there are two file explorer in the taskbar. we want one.

Comment: Then why don't you unpin or delete the one you don't want?

Comment: maybe I am not stating it clearly. For example, you unpin the file explorer(explorer.exe), the taskbar remain one file explorer(created using you method), but when you click on that, another file explorer(explorer.exe) will come up. What we want is only one file explorer show in taskbar

Answer (score 0):

•  Search for Folder Options

•  In the top dropdown menu, select which location you need to open by default